# TFS2012 : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using TFS2012 as source control with VS2012.

When I checkin any file which is checked-out , output window shows this error:

---

ProfileController.cs has been automatically checked out for editing.
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

---

Tried to resolve this(restarted VS2012) and also deleted the server Work-space and recreated again, but the problem is still same.

Any file I checkout in source-control from solution-explorer, does same behavior.

Any help?

Comment: I disconnected Team Project from TFS2012 Service, Reopen VS2012. and then there is no problem. It is resolved now.

Hope It will help somebody else.

Comment: Have you installed the latest updates for TFS and Visaul Studio 2012?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, disconnecting and re-connecting to the TFS2012 Service solved it

Answer (score 1):

I get this error with VS 2012 when I try to check in files. To get around it, I open VS, then immediately go under "Team" and select "Connect to Team Foundation Server..." BEFORE I open any solutions. Then any solutions I open and work on can be checked in without this error appearing.